# Set ultragrid row selected after creating a new row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an ultragrid with lots of rows, new rows are added to the end, I want that when a new row is added, that row is selected and the grid also should scroll to the bottom.

I was going to try ActiveRow but it says it has no setter

```
private void ultraButtonCreateNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
            FormAddUnit form = new FormAddUnit();

            form.BuildingDataSet = _buildingDataSet;
            form.SectionDataSet = _sectionDataSet;
            form.UnitDataSet = _uc011_WizardStepUnitDataSet;
            form.SummaryDataSet = _summaryDataSet;
            form.FormState = WizardState.Create;
            form.Enablement = false;

            dr = form.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                UC011_WizardStepUnitDataSet.UnitRow row = form.GetRow();
                _uc011_WizardStepUnitDataSet.Unit.AddUnitRow(row);
                SetUltraGridData();
                ultraGridOverview.DisplayLayout.ActiveRow = row;
                SetSummaryDataSet();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to select a row and scroll it into the view, you can either call the Activate Method on a row like this

```
ultraGridOverview.Rows[ultraGridOverview.Rows.Count - 1].Activate()
```

or you can set the Position Property of the underlying CurrencyManager

```
CurrencyManager currencymanagerCustomers;
currencymanagerCustomers = this.BindingContext(ultraGridOverview.DataSource);
currencymanagerCustomers.Position = _uc011_WizardStepUnitDataSet.Rows.Count -1;
```

Comment: What about if the row I need to select is in a different band?

Comment: My datasource is hierarchical, one dataset with 2 datatables, and each row in the master table might or might not have child rows in the child table, I need to be able to select a row in the child table and scroll to it, @Andre Kraemer. Please help :)

Comment: My list is sorted. The CurrencyManager is giving me the relative index but I need to get (and set) the absolute one. Any idea?

Comment: **Never mind**. Picking up the selectedIndex on the grid itself is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ultraGrid1_BeforeRowDeactivate(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!first) //Ignore this step if application has just started
    {
       UltraGrid g = (UltraGrid)(sender);
       r = g.ActiveRow;
       ultraGrid1.Rows[g.ActiveRow.Index].Cells["Is Closed"].Value = false; 
    }
}
```

This worked for me, over multiple bands.

r is a global var, which stores the reference to the newly created row.
first is a global bool which is made false at the end of Form_Load.

After the row is inserted/created use the reference to r to modify the row